# Printing an array in AT&T syntax assembly language

Tags: assembly, x86-64, att

I am hardcoding an array and trying to print out its content. I am a beginner in assembly and I am lost on what to go from here. When I run the code the output is 1 and 6295604. If someone can help me fix my errors and print out the error that would be awesome.

```
    .data

arr: .quad 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 
output: .string "%d \n"

.text

.global main
sumarr:
    xor %rax, %rax
    xor %rcx, %rcx

printarr:
    xor %rax, %rax
    decq %rsi
    movq (%rdi, %rsi, 8), %rcx
    movq %rcx, %rax


    cmpq $0, %rsi
    jne printarr
    call fake

    ret

main:

    mov $arr, %rdi  
    mov $5, %rsi
    call sumarr

fake:  

    push %rax   
    push %rcx
    push %rdi


    mov $output, %rdi
    mov %rax, %rsi
    xor %rax, %rax
    call printf

    pop %rax
    pop %rcx
    pop %rdi
    ret
```

Comment: falling through into `fake:` after the `call sumarr` returns looks suspicious.  Single-step your code with a debugger (GDB for example).  See the bottom of https://stackoverflow.com/tags/x86/info for debugging tips.  Also, consider using `.Lfoo` for local labels that are supposed to just be inside functions, not whole functions themselves.

Comment: Also, your `pop %rax` is popping the value pushed by `push %rdi`.  Remember it's a stack.